# mounting a local folder on an ssh server

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, windows-8.1

I want to temporarily mount my local folder on a computationally powerful server so that I can compile my files in parallel there. The server runs linux and I have ssh access to it.
I dont have root access though- but I can talk to the administrator to get something installed.

My local machine(laptop) runs windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

You will basically have to set up a WebDAV or FTP server on your local machine to get the files on the remote machine. I prefer FTP as it is easier. Install [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), this is the best you will find for Windows (free, flexible, opensource and what not...). Open up your ssh into the local machine and get your files up there through ftp. And compile away.

Another setup that I have used on a media server project was using dropbox service. Install dropbox headless for linux. Steps follow. This way the files keep in sync.

1. `cd ~ && wget -O - http://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64 | tar xzf -`. This is for 64 bit, for 32 bit just remove the _64
2. Run the daemon `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`
3. You can use an init script to run it automatically, link here http://pastebin.com/1e7VHD20 (do not forget to change the user name)

Run it immediately without rebooting. On the first run it will configure itself.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should just SCP the contents of your folder to the Linux server. WinSCP works fine for this.